# Sqlite with Blazor (.NET 5) -> System.DllNotFoundException: e_sqlite3 but OK with Windows Forms

Tags: c#, sqlite, blazor

Just getting started with Blazor, trying to use Sqlite using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite library.
Created a data class which works fine in Windows Forms project where underneath the bin folder the  net5.0-windows folder contains a runtimes folder containing e_sqlite3 dlls for various platforms.

Created a simple "Hello World" Blazor web app and added my data class and get following error:

crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection' threw an exception.
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection' threw an exception.
---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
---> System.DllNotFoundException: e_sqlite3

The bin folder does not contain any runtimes folder or the e_sqlite3 dll.

Searching Google this seems to be a common error and is clearly about how the packages get deployed but I have not found a solution.

Ant pointers?

Comment: You should use blazor server template if you want to use sqlite on server side. If you want to use it on client side in blazor webassembly - it's impossible, your maybe should look at `IndexedDB` if this is your case.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'll investigate the alternatives.  I was hoping to keep to the Web Assembly template.  Still getting my head around the whole Blazor technology.
I'm looking for a lightweight portable solution that can run on linux and ideally (and I appreciate that this isn't ready in Blazor "yet") on smartphones too.

Comment: So what kind of data access this lightweight application is supposed to do? If it is pretty simple you can abstract it yourself, making local storage adapter for browser scenarios and file system adapter for others.

Comment: It's actually an old project that I am repurposing and using to try to learn some new technology.  The original database was SqlCompact and I was planning to switch to SQLite, however there are only about 10 tables, with max 10k rows per table so I can look at alternatives.
In the meantime I'm making progress understanding Blazor and Web Assembly.

Answer (score 3):

In .NET 5 you can't use SQLite with Blazor in web app/browser.

However, as of .NET 6, you **can** include native dependencies in Blazor WebAssembly. Inside dotnet conf 2021 they even show show that. It's working very nicely.

You can see this in action here: [Steven Sanderson on Blazor WebAssemby @ .NETConf21](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kesUNeBZ1Os) (approx. 30 minutes watch time).

A code sample for the above is available on [Steve Sanderson's GitHub repo](https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/BlazeOrbital/blob/6b5f7892afbdc96871c974eb2d30454df4febb2c/BlazeOrbital/ManufacturingHub/Properties/NativeMethods.cs#L6).

Comment: As per your answer can you please provide working sample of @Steve Sanderson project for .net 6 blazor wasm sqlite as i am getting this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70076688/sqlite-with-blazor-wasm-net-6-system-dllnotfoundexception-e-sqlite3 your prompt response will be highly appreciated.Thanks