# How to use SQLite in Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: c#, sqlite, blazor, blazor-webassembly

For Blazor WebAssembly I came up with the idea of using SQLite. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66623626/sqlite-with-blazor-net-5-system-dllnotfoundexception-e-sqlite3-but-ok-wit) mentions it is not possible. Is it possible to use SQLite in Blazor WebAssembly and if so, how?

Comment: I can see, its being used here https://executecommands.com/crud-in-blazor-using-sqlite-entity-framework/

Comment: Naaw.. its not. But I misread it too. It was asked this year in March. And yes, I saw this blog entry.. its about Blazor Server.

Comment: If nothing else, the sqlite library is written using native C, and browsers don't let you execute arbitrary C code (it would be very unsafe if they did!). Even if you did manage to compromise the browser, the sqlite library assumes you've got a filesystem, but browsers don't supply you with a filesystem

Comment: You might be best off with [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)

Comment: @canton7 Thank you! I only used Sqlite on Android so far, where an API and a filesystem is given. I'll check IndexedDB

Comment: You might have a look at [this project](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno). It claims to be able to do what you're asking for.

Comment: Coming back to my questions 2 years later, some progress was made :). 
I'm now using this pretty straight forward library from Jeremy Likness which wraps up the SQLite code for various platforms, stores the db file using the Cache API and simply allows you to work with the EF Core DbContext. <3
https://github.com/JeremyLikness/SqliteWasmHelper

Comment: Everything canton7 has written is now false. SQLite indeed runs in the browser and, yes, there is also a file system available on pretty much every browser out there.

Answer (score 13):

As of .NET 6, you can use include native dependencies in Blazor WebAssembly, one example in fact being SQLite. See example code here: https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/BlazeOrbital/blob/6b5f7892afbdc96871c974eb2d30454df4febb2c/BlazeOrbital/ManufacturingHub/Properties/NativeMethods.cs#L6

Comment: You can see this in action here: [Steven Sanderson on Blazor WebAssemby @ .NETConf21](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kesUNeBZ1Os) (watch time ~30mins)

Comment: unfortunately this video from Sanderson is a nice demo only. He doesn't explain his code. I tried to run his code on my local machine it doesn't work. there is no trial/explanation what he has done with the Javascript part connecting to Indexedb.

Comment: I'm also unable to get that example running on my machine and are stuck with the "System.DllNotFoundException: e_sqlite3" that Steve Sanderson easily fixes in the youtube clip posted by @m-smith. So yeah, it's somewhat hard to find a working solution for that.

Answer (score 9):

Starting `.Net 6`, it is now possible to use `SQLite` with `Blazor Web Assembly` .

Here are the steps,

1. Add reference to following Nuget packages.
   a. `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite`
   b. `SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3` - Currently in preview as of posting this answer. This package is to avoid `NativeFileReference` of `e_sqlite3.o`.
2. Add the following in `.csproj` to avoid unwanted warning from popping out.

```
<AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
<EmccExtraLDFlags>-s WARN_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0</EmccExtraLDFlags>
```

3. Add the following code in `Program.cs`. This is required to avoid runtime exception - `Could not find method 'AddYears' on type 'System.DateOnly'`

```cs
public partial class Program 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// FIXME: This is required for EF Core 6.0 as it is not compatible with trimming.
    /// </summary>
    [DynamicallyAccessedMembers(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.All)]
    private static Type _keepDateOnly = typeof(DateOnly);
}
```

4. I'm using sqlite inmemory store. Here is the Code Example.

**Database Model:**

```cs
public class Name
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

**Database Context:**

```cs
public class TestDbCOntext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Name> Names { get; set; } = default!;

    public TestDbCOntext(DbContextOptions<TestDbCOntext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Name>().ToTable("Names");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Name>().HasIndex(x => x.FullName);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Name>().Property(x => x.FullName).UseCollation("nocase");
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Warning)
                .EnableDetailedErrors()
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
    }
}
```

**Page/Component:**

```
<button @onclick="RunEfCore">Run Ef Core</button>

@code {
private async Task RunEfCore()
{
    var connectionStringBuilder = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder { DataSource = ":memory:" };
    var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ToString());

    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TestDbCOntext>()
        .UseSqlite(connection)
        .Options;

    using var db = new TestDbCOntext(options);
    db.Database.OpenConnection();
    await db.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
    var nextId = db.Names!.Count() + 1;
    db.Names.Add(new Name { Id = nextId, FullName = "Abdul Rahman" });
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    Console.WriteLine();
    await foreach (var name in db.Names.AsAsyncEnumerable())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name.FullName);
    }
    db.Database.CloseConnection();
}
}
```

4. For persistance, you can make use of `IndexedDB` from browser and sync to save in your server.

Sample Working Demo can found in my [Github Repo - BlazorWasmEfCore](https://github.com/fingers10/BlazorWasmEFCore)

[Live Demo](https://fingers10.github.io/BlazorWasmEFCore/)

Refer the [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39825) for complete history.

[Steve Sanderson Video Reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kesUNeBZ1Os)

**Screenshot:**
[image: Demo]

**Points to consider:**

The below details are taken from following [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70554776/10851213).

A good rule of programming is KISS - Keep it Simple. So if the requirement of your app is satisfied by Linq to Objects, then complicating it with SQLite would seem to be the wrong thing to do.

However, in the video Steve S. does come up with requirement parameters that lend themselves to using SQLite - the application needs to process:

- lots of data
- in the client
- offline
- quickly
- The use of SQLite here is not for persisting beyond client app memory.

So the answer to your question on the advantage of a Blazor app using SQLite is simply:

- If an app needs the functionality of an in-memory relational database but is trying to avoid using one, it will either be reinventing the wheel in its implementation, or missing necessary functionality.
- If an app doesn't need the functionality of an in-memory database but is using one, it will be introducing unnecessary complexity (cost).

Comment: Interesting, is this method good enough to use in production if the use case is just for in memory storage?

Comment: Yes I think we can use it for in memory storage.

Comment: The main drawback being once the Tab gets refreshed by "F5" or some other mechanism it will be lost correct?

Comment: You can persist using FileSystem API. A word of caution that don't store sensitive data. Refer https://www.thinktecture.com/en/blazor/ef-core-and-sqlite-in-browser/

Comment: I cloned your working demo, but when I click 'Run Ef Core" I get an exception that it is unable to find a dll related to sqlite.

System.DllNotFoundException: e_sqlite3

Anyone have thoughts on remedy?

Comment: I need to check. It's been a long time I've created the repo. And please make sure all nugets are restored properly and the dlls are copied to output.

Answer (score 1):

Your Blazor WebAssembly C# code still runs in the sandbox of the browser, that means it is not allowed to open files on the local drive.

Blazor WebAssembly has the same access to the machine as any regular website.

Even if someone was to port SQLite to WebAssembly you would not be able to open a database file.

For storage on the client computer you are limited to Local Storage, it is limited to 5 MB (might be different per browser brand) and can only contain strings. But it is not a reliable option as the data will be removed when the users clears the cache, browser history etc..

The only option you have is storing data on the server.

Comment: Thanks once more. Since canton7 answered my question, I started some tests with IndexedDb. As of what I found out, it is possible to store theoretically up to 2 GB per "group", according to the [mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria#storage_limits).
And yes, its still part of the cache and gets deleted when the cache is cleared by the user. However, it seems to be the best solution so far. 
Ah. And yes, definitly, there is a persistance layer on the backend.

Comment: IndexedDb sounds interesting. It seems to be supported by all browsers. Thank you.

Comment: Fortunately all of those limitations are history today.