# Is it possible/concievable to use System.Data.SQLite in Blazor WASM?

Tags: sqlite, blazor, webassembly

I'm looking into using SQLite in a client-side Blazor app. One of the features I'm interested in using is the virtual table mechanism. I've been happily using this facility in System.Data.SQLite via the SQLiteModule class. However, I can't seem to get System.Data.SQLite to work in Blazor WASM.

Pulling the System.Data.SQLite Nuget package into my Blazor project works fine as far as the managed DLLs go, but the SQLite.Interop.dll fails to load at runtime. Since this is a native DLL (or is it mixed?) the runtime can't load it and JIT it to WASM, so that makes sense.

But is it possible to compile the native SQLite.Interop.dll to WASM?

Comment: It's possible, just not with *that* package. WASM runs on the browser so you need a WASM implementation. [SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3/) works in-memory and [SqliteWasmHelper](https://github.com/JeremyLikness/SqliteWasmHelper) adds storage to the browser's cache.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos do you know if I can implement custom virtual tables using that package?

Comment: It is just SQLite. If you can do it normally, you can do it in WASM too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use SQLite in Blazor WebAssembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67966259/how-to-use-sqlite-in-blazor-webassembly)