# Sqlite with Blazor Wasm (.NET 6) -> System.DllNotFoundException: e_sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, blazor, webassembly

as per New Blazor WebAssembly capabilities in .NET 6 New Blazor WebAssembly capabilities in .NET 6

Sqlite with Blazor Wasm (.NET 6) -> System.DllNotFoundException: e_sqlite3

can anyone have the working sample after compiling Sqlite3.o file

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this issue?

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Answer (score 8):

I got a Solution for out Problem.

Following this Tutorial:
[ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly native dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-native-dependencies?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

You need to Install ".NET WebAssembly build tools"

Open Command Line & Type:

dotnet workload install wasm-tools

Comment: i did that and i m still getting the error. I ve been looking two days now for a solution. Any other ideas? I have installed the wasm tools net6, since i m developing a .net 6 wasm app, and also checked the AOT option. When i open the app in the browser, i get this error.